# What happens when you add n Cauchy random variables that have a positive correlation?

Tags: probability, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

The reason the law of large numbers fails to apply for the Cauchy distribution is that the distribution of $X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots X_n$ is the same as $X_1+X_1+\dots X_1 = n X_1$. This is billed a curious property by Feller on page 51 of his book: An introduction to probability theory and its applications, volume 2 first edition. In the first case, we're adding $n$ independent random variables and in the second one, we're adding $n$ perfectly dependent random variables with correlation as high as it can get (they're all literally the same variable). And yet, we end up with the same resulting distribution.

---

EDIT: The argument regarding the variances being different is resolved because they blow up. The question that remains is that in the title. We know adding $n$ perfectly dependent Cauchy's is equivalent to the first Cauchy scaled by $n$. And adding $n$ perfectly independent Cauchy's is also the first Cauchy scaled by $n$. What happens if we add $n$ Cauchy's that are correlated but not perfectly? Do we still get the first Cauchy scaled by $n$?

---

**The argument regarding variances that was addressed**

But thinking about the variance of the two sums, this doesn't seem to add up. When the variables are independent we have:

$$Var(X_1+X_2+\dots X_n) = n Var(X_1) \tag{1}$$

And for the second sum we have:

$$Var(X_1+X_1+ \dots X_1) = Var(n X_1) = n^2 Var(X_1) \tag{2}$$

It's clear the second sum has a higher variance due to the covariance terms which are not there in the first case. But if the two have difference variances, then how can they have the same distribution? And if they somehow do have the same variance, what happens when the covariance between the random variables is somewhere between complete independence and the variables being replicas of the same thing?

Comment: Cauchy disrtribtuion does not have finite mean, let alone variance.

Comment: Right, forgot that.. thanks! But one question remains; what if I add $n$ Cauchy that are correlated (not the same but have a positive correlation). Is the resulting distribution still the same as $n X_1$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Multivariate_Cauchy_distribution

Comment: Thanks Oliver. That doesn't seem to tell me what happens when I add them. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RohitPandey If $X$ has Cauchy distribution then $-X$ has Cauchy distribution too but $X+(-X)$ does not have Cauchy distribution.

Comment: See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386036/quantifying-dependence-of-cauchy-random-variables#
The covaraince between Cauchy random variables is undefined - as the first moment is undefined. As stated above, we can use the idea of multivariate T distribution to model the dependence structure between them. More generally, we can use a general copula to model this. In such way a parameter of dependence can be introduced.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - it is a Cauchy with scale $0$.